# Join Two queries and find output: PostgresSql

Tags: postgresql

Want join the below two queries and want to give the output as following:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM trip_schedule_close ts
WHERE    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ts.schedule_date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM current_date)
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ts.schedule_date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date)  AND  ts.route_id='152'
```

This query will give_output as:

### count

14

Next Query:

```
SELECT sum(ts.product_qty)AS Product_Quantity FROM trip_delivery_sales_lines ts
WHERE    EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ts.order_date) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM current_date)
AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM ts.order_date) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM current_date) AND ts.route_id='152' AND ts.product_id='432'  AND ts.type='sales'
```

This query will output result as:

### product Quantity

446565

N0w i want join these two queries and want to give result as :

446565/ 14

Comment: Does your 2 queries return always only one row?

Comment: Yes.in first query count and 2nd query sum

Answer (score 0):

First rewrite your first query as :

```
SELECT count(*) AS nb FROM t...
```

Then , assuming sql1 & sql2 are your 2 queries

```
SELECT Product_Quantity || '/ ' || nb AS new_name FROM ( sql1 ) r1,( sql2 ) r2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with
    p(curr_month, route_id, product_id, type) as (values(
        date_trunc('month', current_date),
        152,
        432,
        'sales'::text))
select
    (SELECT count(*)
     FROM trip_schedule_close ts
     WHERE
         date_trunk('month', ts.schedule_date) = p.curr_month AND
         ts.route_id = p.route_id) || '/' ||
    (SELECT sum(ts.product_qty) AS Product_Quantity
     FROM trip_delivery_sales_lines ts
     WHERE
         date_trunk('month', ts.schedule_date) = p.curr_month AND
         ts.route_id = p.route_id AND
         ts.product_id = p.product_id AND
         ts.type = p.type)
FROM p;
```